# Java - my paint program needs a menu bar with a submenu with an image - how to do?

Tags: java, image, jframe, jpanel, javax.imageio

SO I have this program that is kind of like paint, it lets you draw shapes and lines, but my assignment is to add a menu bar with a sub menu File-> About, when Click on the about section.  It should pull up a panel or a frame or a something that has a image which I have already made.
However it's not working and I have never actually dealt with images before.  All I have is from a Google search and that failed.  I know the method is being called from the delightful system.out.println, and a box opens up but there is no picture!~ any help would be very nice.

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("About"))
{
    System.out.println("stfu");
    JFrame about = new JFrame("About");
    about.setSize(300, 300);
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try{
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/TehRobot/Desktop/Logo.png"));
    }catch (IOException e1)
    {

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't leave the catch block empty. At least print the stack trace of the exception so you know when something goes wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to ...

- Read in the Image with ImageIO.read(...)
- Put your Image into an ImageIcon via the ImageIcon constructor
- Put the ImageIcon into a JLabel via JLabel's `setIcon(...)` method.
- And display that JLabel in a dialog such as a JOptionPane (super easy to do) or a modal JDialog (a little more complicated, but not much).

In all this should just take a few lines of code, that's all.

Comment: @CalvinMoss then you wont learn anything besides how to copy and paste. Writing code is the fun part anyway :)